# Sitecore custom backend app

Tags: .net, sitecore, backend

I try to find some about custom backend application in sitecore.
Can anybody tell me how to build new application in sitecore backend like "Content Editor", "Developer Center" or other in desktop mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a great article about creating **Sitecore** **Sheer UI** applications:

[My First Sheer UI Application](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XML%20Sheer%20UI/My%20first%20XML%20application.aspx)

Edit after @Martijn comment: You can add ASP.net Webforms applications into **Sitecore** desktop as well. Here are some links explaining how to do this:

[Sitecore Desktop Application](http://www.tanasuk.com/en/Blog/Sitecore%20Desktop%20Application.aspx)

[External application inside Sitecore Desktop](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/external-application-inside-sitecore-desktop/)

Comment: You don't need to use SheerUI, you could also create custom backend applications with the use of ASP.NET Webforms. Sitecore itself will also move away from SheerUi in one of the next versions.

Comment: If you have Sitecore Rocks installed, which I would highly recommend. It already has the SPEAK templates in, although I haven't found any documentation as to how SPEAK works yet. I believe the Email Campaign manager screens are written using SPEAK. (SPEAK is Sitecores new HTML5/Javascipt/Webforms way that will replace SheerUI)